# Getting all addresses on a street - Google Maps Geocoding API

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api, tiger-lines

My task is to take a specific street and find all of the houses on that street. My input is a complete address with city, zip, etc - except without the house number. The desired output is a literal list of every home on that street and their respective house numbers. (411 Street Dr., 413 Street Dr.)

I can't find anything in the Maps / Geocoding API which provides this functionality, or even something similar like finding all of the addresses within a polygon.

The only real solution is to "guess" house numbers on the street and verify whether not it's a real address. To make this slightly more accurate, the TIGER database could potentially be leveraged. It does include "address ranges" for streets, such as "400 - 432".

**My question is: does anybody know of alternate API or another combination which provides complete results (every address 99% of the time)?**

It is so burdensome to make that many requests and having to essentially throw most of them in the trash!

PS. The Places API will not work here because the need is residential homes.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps APIs do not offer bulk download of maps data as you seem to be looking for. You can use the APIs to let users find places, but they are not for you to obtain exhaustive maps data sets.

Maybe you can use the Google Maps APIs to build your application/s in such a way that you don't really need to have all houses in each street, enabling each user to find the one place s/he needs.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are certain API's for obtaining the mailing routes of a particular area, which would have the entire street laid out in it. These however cost money and not all streets have linear iteration. This would probably be the easiest and perhaps the most accurate way of doing it.
2. I would alternatively write a program that would take the street name, iterate through (presumably an extremely large) list of possible numbers, and plug those possible house numbers into Google Maps to see if those houses exist. Of course you could filter the process a number of ways such as counting the number of numbers in the address name and such; however as I said not all street numberings are linear. Also I just noticed you referenced a "Tiger" database which contains the address number ranges. That would be an effective way of using this strategy.